# sum timestamp difference (time)

Tags: oracle11g, sum

I want to sum the difference of time of field datetime (timestamp)

select sum(max(datetime)-min(datetime)) from archivo;

it shows me :

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Please Helpe me.

Thanks in advance.